# How to find if the lat.lng is within a certain radius circle in google maps

Tags: android, google-maps

I have the sample entries for

- **lat**: 12.962899
- **lng** 77.622330

I have drawn a circle in the map of a radius of `10000`

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
     .center(new LatLng(lat, lng))
     .radius(10000)
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE));
```

**What I am trying to do**: If i am given a new `lat`,`lng` value, I want to find out if the new position is within the circle radius or not.

How to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find out distance between 2 lat longs using this function

```
 private float calculateLocationDifference(LatLng lastLocation, LatLng firstLocation) {
        float[] dist = new float[1];
        Location.distanceBetween(lastLocation.latitude, lastLocation.longitude, firstLocation.latitude, firstLocation.longitude, dist);
        return dist[0];
    }
```

pass center point of circle and new point to it . if distance is < 10000 then location is with in the circle

Comment: I only saw your answer after posting mine, but if we are talking about using google maps then you will most likely have LatLng objects and if that the case your method is better solution ratter than my solution. You got my upvote and thank you for showing me this nice and simple solution.

Comment: @TamirAbutbul its ok , happens lot of times to me as well, writing answer takes time . Appreciate your effort as well .

Answer (score 2):

You can look at it as a [coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system), let's say that you are putting the first point on the map.

You are adding a new point and want to check if it's inside your circle, because your circle has a radius of `10000` you can compare the distance between your points (new and old) and if this distance is `> 10000` your new point is not inside the circle.

If you are using google maps you can use [distanceBetween](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D)) method to find the distance:

```
  Location.distanceBetween(FirstLatitude, FirstLongitude, SecondLatitude, SecondLongitude, results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function:
It will return a boolean true or false
point = {lat: 12.962899, lng: 77.622330}
or you can get the points from click event

```
function pointInCircle(point, radius, center) {
    return (google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(point, center) <= radius)
}
```